# How to render inline css in Haml in Rails 3.2?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I have the following code in the `<head>` tag of a Rails haml view file.  I am running Rails 3.2.11 with the [haml gem version 4.0.6](https://rubygems.org/gems/haml/versions/4.0.6)

```
:css
  body { background-color: red !important;}
```

Unfortunately, it is not rendering in the final html output.  I tried:

```
%style {:style => "text/css" }
  body { background-color: red !important;}
```

But that doesn't render either.  What am I missing?

Comment: Your `:css` filter code is correct. What is the surrounding code, and what is the output?

Comment: There is no output code unfortunately that's what is baffling.